# Return functions in an recursiv function

Tags: python, function, recursion, python-2.x

I m trying to make a code to do this:

```
how many 'SOS!' do you want to call? 5
SOS!SOS!SOS!SOS!SOS!
```

but all i can come up with is this

```
print "please tell me how bad your situation is, how many SOS! do you want to call?"

def help(n):
    if n <= 0:
        print "Don't SOS! if you don't need help!"
    elif n > 1:
        print "SOS!"
        help(n-1)
    else:
        print "SOS!"

help(input("how many SOS! do you need to call?"))
```

does anybody have any solution how i can fix this?

Comment: Fix it? What makes you think something's wrong with it?

Comment: I just ran your code and it works fine... What's your problem?

Comment: Is your question just about getting all the SOS's on one line? If so, perhaps you should edit the question to say explicitly what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

I am not understanding what your question is. The code for help(n) is correct.

You only need to check the input and then run your function help:

```
print "how many SOS! do you want to call? "
int n = input()
print n
help(n).
```

Comment: You did not provide an answer. Please put suggestions into comments instead.

Comment: Sorry but i did provide an answer. The code is correct and working.